# Incented or Incentivized?

Tags: word-choice

What is the correct adjective to describe someone who has been given an incentive? Incented or incentivized? I have heard/seen both.

Comment: I've never heard/seen incented.  I would use incentivized.

Comment: Dictionary.com says [they're synonymous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/incented) so use whichever.

Comment: I wish there were a "vote to close because words like this just shouldn't exist" button.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Why not? It's useful to have a word meaning 'to give an incentive'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be **incentivized**. 
According to the Merriam-Webster online dictionary, **incentivize** is a valid verb meaning "to provide with an incentive."
Incentivized is kind of a letdown. I was hoping for incentivated (like motivated).

Comment: You could start saying *[motivized](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=koGD6XnAsNs)*.

Comment: From [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=incented%2Cincentivized%2Cincentivated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=5), it looks like *incented, incentivated*, and *incentivized* are all used, with *incentivized* being the winner. One comment ... the pre-1960 uses of *incented* seem mostly to be typos for (or a variant form of) *incensed*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand all the fuss over [incentivise](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/incentivise) - it seems like a perfectly ordinary word to me, and Chambers 2011 have no problem listing it. I will admit it wasn't in their 1983 edition - but even if I can't recall exactly how I felt about the word back then, I doubt I'd have objected to it.

*Incented* sounds really odd/ignorant to me, but [Google Books](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22business%20complimentaries%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#pq=incent&hl=en&ds=bo&cp=8&gs_id=1s&xhr=t&q=incented&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=incented&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=941366e8cd19fa00&biw=1123&bih=893) records it 3950 times, so perhaps I'm overreacting. Even so, it's blown away by over 27000 instances of [incentivised](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22business%20complimentaries%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=incentivised&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=941366e8cd19fa00&biw=1123&bih=893&pf=p&pdl=500) / [incentivized](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22business%20complimentaries%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=incentivized&pbx=1&oq=incentivized&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=35530l36219l6l36490l2l1l1l0l0l0l103l103l0.1l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=941366e8cd19fa00&biw=1123&bih=893).

Answer (score 0):

if you say "incentivized"  you mean "promoting (something) with a particular incentive". So, 
**motivated** would be more appropriate.

> ...highly motivated employees.

Comment: 'Motivated' would normally imply 'self-motivated' unless the context said otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Both possibilities assume incentive has a verb form. It does not.

Just say "someone who has been given an incentive", or choose a variation like "encouraged" or "induced".

Comment: Saying so don't make it so. I don't like the verb "incentivis/ze" either, but the claim that it doesn't exist is false.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Go, Brits! Nice to see the "s" version (which I don't mind at all) acknowledged before the "z" one (which I don't much like either, but probably not for the same reason as you! :)

Comment: Why make a new verb with a clear meaning when we can fall back on clumsy phrases or verbs that mean something else?